# Elasticsearch. SKU analyze and search

Tags: elasticsearch, query-analyzer

It makes me mad already, I've tried everything I can with this.
Here is the thing. I need to:

1. transform all similar looking russian letters to english (while analyzing and search requests)
2. remove all non-alphabetical and non-digits
3. make tokens with ngram case search can be from any place of string

For example you can search for 8009, and I have ALK-8009 and ALK-8022 sku's, I can't understand why ALK-8022 goes above ALK-8009.

```
      index_options: {
        settings: {
          index: {
            analysis: {
              char_filter: {
                russian_transliteration: {
                  type: "mapping",
                  mappings: ["а=>a",
                             "в=>b",
                             "е=>e",
                             "к=>k",
                             "м=>m",
                             "н=>h",
                             "о=>o",
                             "р=>p",
                             "с=>c",
                             "т=>t",
                             "у=>u",
                             "х=>x"]
                },
                pattern_replace_char_filter: {
                  type: "pattern_replace",
                  pattern: "(\\s|[-_\/\.\(\)])*",
                  replacement: ""
                }
              },
              tokenizer: {
                sku_tokenizer: {
                  type: "nGram",
                  min_gram: 4,
                  max_gram: 15
                },
                sku_search_tokenizer: {
                  type: "edgeNGram",
                  min_gram: 4,
                  max_gram: 15
                }
              },
              analyzer: {
                sku_analyzer: {
                  type: "custom",
                  tokenizer: "sku_tokenizer",
                  char_filter: ["russian_transliteration","pattern_replace_char_filter"],
                  filter: ['lowercase']

                }
                },
                sku_search_analyzer: {
                  type: "custom",
                  tokenizer: "sku_search_tokenizer",
                  char_filter: ["russian_transliteration","pattern_replace_char_filter"],
                  filter: ['lowercase']
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      index_mappings: {
         sku: {
              type: 'string',
              analyzer: 'sku_analyzer',
              fields: {
                search: {type: 'string', analyzer: 'sku_search_analyzer'},
                suggest:  {type: 'completion'}
              }
          }
      }
```

And here is my search query:

```
{query: 
  {bool: 
    {should: 
      [{prefix: {sku: {value: "SEARCH-STRING", boost: 2}}}, 
       {match: {sku: {query: "SEARCH-STRING", boost: 1, fuzziness: 0}}}]
}}}
```

What I expect to have, only those results, that have full search string in SKU, not just part.

for example, ALK-80 - will transform to alk80 and only those results are what I need.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) why your query doesn't use the `sku.search` sub-field? and 2) why do you index your SKUs with the nGram tokenizer and search them with edgeNgram?

Comment: @Val, 1) I have bunch of other query parts, that's why I use bool query (on other fields), 2) I expect elastic to tokenize my sku to tokens which I the use to search. But I need only those tokens from start of the string, that's why I used edgeNgram. 

I'm sure I'm mistaking, I've spend almost 2 month to do that, how do you think I should do this search?

Comment: I'm sure you're not that far off. Can you provide a small gist that will easily allow to re-create your problem (i.e. curl to create index/mapping + put a few sample SKUs)?

Comment: Also can you specify which version of ES you're running?

Comment: @Val, I can't believe it. After I started doing some examples for you, just requests to marvel, I found out, that it works exactly how I want. And I spent lots of time because of different settings and invalid cache of my wrapper around elastic. The only thing I changed is that I started to use keyword tokenizer in my sku_search_analyzer. Thank you man.

Comment: Well, perfect then, glad if you figured it out!